# Add html plugin into wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I purchased an HTML5 Video & Youtube background plugin,

I want to use it with WordPress.

http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-youtube-background/1555660

Any Suggestions? Maybe create a template, page,etc..?

Comment: They say, that the examples included. Are they helpful?

Comment: Also, there are support and comments pages http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-youtube-background/1555660/support

Answer (score 0):

How experienced are you with WordPress? You could create a Page Template just like you would for a HTML-only website and use the code there. If you are trying to implement it into your WordPress installation to be able to change the content from the Admin, you'll have to do a whole lot more.